# How to display the portfolio of a specific type?

Tags: wordpress

I am using webphysiology_portfolio plugin in my wordpress website.
This plugin have the portfolio types.

When I user this short code `[webphysiology_portfolio]` , It displays all portfolios on the page.

But I want to display the portfolios of a specific type.
So what is the short code I will use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example taken from: http://webphysiology.com/plugins/webphysiology-portfolio-plugin/#portfolio

```
[webphysiology_portfolio portfolio_type=red]
```

Here's a screenshot taken from the same page:
[image: Screenshot of examples of how to use]